# Multi-variable calculus and a Table Interpretation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was given the following table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
& \color{red}{15} & \color{red}{20} &\color{red}{25} &\color{red}{30} \\ \hline \color{blue}3&71&74&77&79 \\ \hline \color{blue}4&62&\bbox[yellow]{66}&70&73\\ \hline \color{blue}5&53&59&63&67 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
The red quantities represents Air Temperature in Celsius, and the blue quantities represent Wet-bulb depression in Celsius.  The wet bulb depression is measured as the difference between the air temperature, and the wet bulb thermostat measurement, or as follows:
$$\text{wet-bulb depression}=\text{air temperature}-\text{wet bulb thermostat measurement}$$
The table is the representation of a multi-variable function. I was then given to solve for the relative humidity which happens to be the black text parts.

### Question

What is the relative humidity if the air temperature is $20^\circ\mathrm{C}$ and the wet bulb temperature measurement is $16^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$

I calculated that the relative humidity is about 66% which is highlighted in yellow.

## My question

Is that whether all multi-variable functions or at least two variable expressions can fit into this chart kind of scheme, as well as would I expect the function to look like this?
$$f(\text{air temperature},\text{wet-bulb depression})=\text{relative humidity}$$

Comment: You will have some object as inputs, almost always a tupple of variables (e.g. $(x,y,z),$ but there is no restriction that you will have as few as 3-dimensions of inputs), and some object as outputs, sometimes a single value, but sometimes a vector.  $F(\text {price of raw goods, mark-up, wages, tax rates, units}) = (\text {margins, taxes, profits})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I suppose that this answer will horrify statisticians.*

To take advantage of the table in spite of the small number of data points,we could in a first step consider a complete quadratic surface
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z \\
 3 & 15 & 71 \\
 3 & 20 & 74 \\
 3 & 25 & 77 \\
 3 & 30 & 79 \\
 4 & 15 & 62 \\
 4 & 20 & 66 \\
 4 & 25 & 70 \\
 4 & 30 & 73 \\
 5 & 15 & 53 \\
 5 & 20 & 59 \\
 5 & 25 & 63 \\
 5 & 30 & 67
\end{array}
\right)$$
and try 
$$z=a+b x+c y+d x y+e x^2+f y^2$$ A first multilinear regression would give
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +93.5167 & 3.82595 & \{+83.6817,+103.352\} \\
 b & -12.6500 & 1.57615 & \{-16.7016,-8.59838\} \\
 c & +0.57333 & 0.17884 & \{+0.11361,+1.03305\} \\
 d & +0.19000 & 0.01949 & \{+0.13989,+0.24011\} \\
 e & +0.12500 & 0.18875 & \{-0.36019,+0.61019\} \\
 f & -0.01333 & 0.00356 & \{-0.02249,-0.00418\} 
\end{array}$$ where we can notice that parameter $e$ is not significant. So, let us remove it from the model and repeat with
$$z=a+b x+c y+d x y+f y^2$$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +91.6000 & 2.60986 & \{+84.8911,+98.3089\} \\
 b & -11.6500 & 0.47135 & \{-12.8616,-10.4384\} \\
 c & +0.57333 & 0.18652 & \{+0.09387,+1.05279\} \\
 d & +0.19000 & 0.02033 & \{+0.13774,+0.24226\} \\
 f & -0.01333 & 0.00371 & \{-0.02287,-0.00379\} 
\end{array}$$ where now all parameters are significant.

The table below reports the original data and the values predicted by the model
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x & y  & z  & z_{\text{calc}} \\
 3 & 15 & 71 & 70.80 \\
 3 & 20 & 74 & 74.18 \\
 3 & 25 & 77 & 76.90 \\
 3 & 30 & 79 & 78.95 \\
 4 & 15 & 62 & 62.00 \\
 4 & 20 & 66 & 66.33 \\
 4 & 25 & 70 & 70.00 \\
 4 & 30 & 73 & 73.00 \\
 5 & 15 & 53 & 53.20 \\
 5 & 20 & 59 & 58.48 \\
 5 & 25 & 63 & 63.10 \\
 5 & 30 & 67 & 67.05
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seems to be quite good for *interpolation*.